# TensorFlow variable float64 and float32

Tags: r, tensorflow

I am a new to TensorFlow 1.8 and i am using it with R.
I am trying to create a variable float32.

```
t <- array(0, dim = 3600000)
TF_t <- tf$Variable(t,tf$float32,name="t")
```

But TensorFlow saves `TF_t` as a `tf$float64`.

```
TF_t
<tf.Variable 't:0' shape=(3600000,) dtype=float64_ref>
```

I know that the easy solution is `tf$cast(TF_t,tf$float32)`, but i would like a solution that doesn't use cast and I would like to know why do i have this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround to cast, but, why this behaviour is there is due to the fact that you decide on a default type for a tensor, in this float64, it is implicitly set in its constructor. Also, losses do need 64 bits most of the time given how much they vary and how low they can go.

As for the cast operation, it is actually the explicit setting of the type.